# Issue with Button on Outlook Email

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, outlook

I am able to make button specific to outlook, but as my EMAIL contains different sections so that button got wrapped in v:rect, and now it is moving to top of email. Please help

Actual Image - [image]

Expected Image - [image]

Relevant code -

```
  <!--[if mso]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
 <!--[if mso]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:730px;" height='auto'>
                <v:fill type="tile" src="" /> 
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">    
            <![endif]-->
            <div><div style="font-size:0;line-height:0;">    
            <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0; width: 100%; position: relative;">                       
                <tbody>                
                    <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">                       
                        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first " style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 16px; max-width: 568px; width: 274px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 16px;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                            <th style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">
                                <p style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 10px; Margin-bottom: 10px;">asdasd</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
<th class="small-12 large-6 columns last " style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 16px; width: 274px; padding-left: 8px; max-width: 568px; padding-right: 16px;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                            <th style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">
                                <div class="editor-button" style="text-align: left;">
    <!--[if mso]>
        <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#empty" style="height: 40px;width: 120px;v-text-anchor: middle;position:relative;" arcsize="8%" strokecolor="#3165C5" fillcolor="#3165C5">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color: #fff;font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;font-weight: 400;text-transform: uppercase;">Button</center>
        </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]> <!---->
        <a href="#empty" style="color: #fff;background-color: #3165C5;border-color: #3165C5;display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;font-style: normal;cursor: default;position: relative;top: 0;font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 14px;width: 120px;line-height: 40px;border-radius: 3px;" target="_blank">Button</a>
    <!-- <![endif]--></div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>                       
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>             
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
```

Here's the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!-- Media queries are added in style block as Juice cannot inline them -->
        <style type="text/css"> @media only screen {
    html {
        min-height: 100%;
        background: #f3f3f3;
    }
    table.body {
        width: 100%; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    center {
        width: 100%; 
        min-width: 0px !important;
    }

    table.body table.container {
        width: 100%; 
        max-width: 584px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    table.container img {
        max-width: 552px;
    }

    table.container table.row th {
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    table.container table.row img {
        max-width: 520px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    .small-float-center {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    .small-text-center {
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    .small-text-left {
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    .small-text-right {
        text-align: right !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    .hide-for-large {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    table.body table.container .hide-for-large,
    table.body table.container .row.hide-for-large {
        display: table !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    table.body table.container .callout-inner.hide-for-large {
        display: table-cell !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    table.body table.container .show-for-large {
        display: none !important;
        width: 0;
        mso-hide: all;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 596px) {
    table.body center {
        min-width: 0 !important;
    }

    table.body .container {
        width: 95% !important;
    }

    table.body .columns,
    table.body .column {
        height: auto !important;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 16px !important;
        padding-right: 16px !important;
    }

    table.body .columns .column,
    table.body .columns .columns,
    table.body .column .column,
    table.body .column .columns {
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }

    table.body .collapse .columns,
    table.body .collapse .column {
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }

    td.small-1,
    th.small-1 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 8.33333% !important;
    }

    td.small-2,
    th.small-2 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 16.66667% !important;
    }

    td.small-3,
    th.small-3 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 25% !important;
    }

    td.small-4,
    th.small-4 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 33.33333% !important;
    }

    td.small-5,
    th.small-5 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 41.66667% !important;
    }

    td.small-6,
    th.small-6 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 50% !important;
    }

    td.small-7,
    th.small-7 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 58.33333% !important;
    }

    td.small-8,
    th.small-8 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 66.66667% !important;
    }

    td.small-9,
    th.small-9 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 75% !important;
    }

    td.small-10,
    th.small-10 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 83.33333% !important;
    }

    td.small-11,
    th.small-11 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 91.66667% !important;
    }

    td.small-12,
    th.small-12 {
        display: inline-block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .columns td.small-12,
    .column td.small-12,
    .columns th.small-12,
    .column th.small-12 {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-1,
    table.body th.small-offset-1 {
        margin-left: 8.33333% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-2,
    table.body th.small-offset-2 {
        margin-left: 16.66667% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-3,
    table.body th.small-offset-3 {
        margin-left: 25% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-4,
    table.body th.small-offset-4 {
        margin-left: 33.33333% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-5,
    table.body th.small-offset-5 {
        margin-left: 41.66667% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-6,
    table.body th.small-offset-6 {
        margin-left: 50% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-7,
    table.body th.small-offset-7 {
        margin-left: 58.33333% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-8,
    table.body th.small-offset-8 {
        margin-left: 66.66667% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-9,
    table.body th.small-offset-9 {
        margin-left: 75% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-10,
    table.body th.small-offset-10 {
        margin-left: 83.33333% !important;
    }

    table.body td.small-offset-11,
    table.body th.small-offset-11 {
        margin-left: 91.66667% !important;
    }

    table.body table.columns td.expander,
    table.body table.columns th.expander {
        display: none !important;
    }

    table.body .right-text-pad,
    table.body .text-pad-right {
        padding-left: 10px !important;
    }

    table.body .left-text-pad,
    table.body .text-pad-left {
        padding-right: 10px !important;
    }

    table.menu {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    table.menu td,
    table.menu th {
        width: auto !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
    }

    table.menu.vertical td,
    table.menu.vertical th,
    table.menu.small-vertical td,
    table.menu.small-vertical th {
        display: block !important;
    }

    table.menu[align="center"] {
        width: auto !important;
    }

    table.button.small-expand,
    table.button.small-expanded {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    table.button.small-expand table,
    table.button.small-expanded table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table.button.small-expand table a,
    table.button.small-expanded table a {
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }

    table.button.small-expand center,
    table.button.small-expanded center {
        min-width: 0;
    }
}
 </style>
    </head>
    <body style="min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; Margin: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; background: #f3f3f3; width: 100%;">
        <center style="width: 100%;">
        <table class="body" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; background: #f3f3f3; height: 100%; width: 100%; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; Margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;background-color: #f3f3f3">
            <!--[if mso]>
                <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                    <v:fill type="tile" color=#f3f3f3 src=/>
                </v:background>
            <![endif]-->
            <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; vertical-align: top; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; Margin: 0 auto; float: none; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <center style="width: 100%;">
                        <table class="container" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; background: #fefefe; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: inherit; max-width: 584px;">
                            <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                                <td style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto; vertical-align: top; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; margin: 0; Margin: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; border-collapse: collapse;">
                                     <!--[if mso]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:730px;" height='auto'>
                <v:fill type="tile" src="" /> 
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">    
            <![endif]-->
            <div><div style="font-size:0;line-height:0;">    
            <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0; width: 100%; position: relative;">                       
                <tbody>                
                    <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">                       
                        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last " style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 16px; width: 560px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; max-width: 552px;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                            <th style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">
                                <p style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 10px; Margin-bottom: 10px;">asdasd</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>                       
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>             
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
 <!--[if mso]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:730px;" height='auto'>
                <v:fill type="tile" src="" /> 
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">    
            <![endif]-->
            <div><div style="font-size:0;line-height:0;">    
            <table class="row" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0; width: 100%; position: relative;">                       
                <tbody>                
                    <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">                       
                        <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first " style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 16px; max-width: 568px; width: 274px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 16px;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                            <th style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">
                                <p style="Margin: 0 0 0 10px; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin-bottom: 10px; Margin-bottom: 10px;">asdasd</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>
<th class="small-12 large-6 columns last " style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0 auto; padding-bottom: 16px; width: 274px; padding-left: 8px; max-width: 568px; padding-right: 16px;">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">
                            <th style="word-break: break-word; color: #0a0a0a; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; padding: 0; text-align: left; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">
                                <div class="editor-button" style="text-align: left;">
    <!--[if mso]>
        <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#empty" style="height: 40px;width: 120px;v-text-anchor: middle;position:relative;" arcsize="8%" strokecolor="#3165C5" fillcolor="#3165C5">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color: #fff;font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;font-style: normal;text-decoration: none;font-weight: 400;text-transform: uppercase;">Button</center>
        </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]> <!---->
        <a href="#empty" style="color: #fff;background-color: #3165C5;border-color: #3165C5;display: inline-block;text-decoration: none;margin-bottom: 0;font-weight: 400;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;font-style: normal;cursor: default;position: relative;top: 0;font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 14px;width: 120px;line-height: 40px;border-radius: 3px;" target="_blank">Button</a>
    <!-- <![endif]--></div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </th>                       
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>             
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--[if mso]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
    <!-- prevent Gmail on iOS font size manipulation -->
   <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please only include code that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I have added full code to not confuse, you can use above code and tweak it to provide the answer, if you want i am adding relevant code as well

Comment: It looks fine in the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yx8oernL/1/

Comment: Issue is on outlook email not on browser

Answer (score 0):

I also work on email development. If we create button like we create in web page it will not show correct layout in Outlook. So i code for button like this.

```
<table class="center-align" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="250">
        <tr>
            <td class="btn-table" style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #ffffff;padding:17px 25px;color:#003580;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;" bgcolor="#003580">
                <a href="#" class="btn-style" style="font-size:16px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#003580;text-align:right;text-decoration:none;display:block;background-color:#ffffff;" title="">Button</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Write this code inside the td block where you want to show button style it accordingly. 1 more thing user is only able to click it when user click the text of button. Because button style is applied to the parent td tag of anchor.

Comment: I tried above approach, cons of above approach is -
1. As you mentioned whole button is not clickable,
2. border-radius does not work on outlook

Comment: cons of above approach is ? Any way i already shared the cons. But your button will look fine with this approach.

Comment: Outlook does not support border radius. i have not find anything for border radius to work on Outlook, please share if you find something that can help to work border radius on outlook. If you found my answer is some what useful you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you're trying to display a `v:roundrect` *inside* a `v:rect`. Nested VML shapes do not work, you have to either rid of the outer `v:rect` or use a table-based "text button" that does not use VML.